# wasAcknowledged flag implementation in mongodb 3.3.0 above

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Our existing code consists of few actions based on the writeResult on the collection operations like:

```
WriteResult writeResult = dbCollection.insert(new BasicDBObject(someDoc));
    if(writeResult.wasAcknowledged()) {
        response.setSuccess(true);
    }
```

Changing operations with upgraded mongo results in something like follows :

```
WriteResult writeResult = dbCollection.insertOne(new BasicDBObject(someDoc)); // this won't work
    if (writeResult.wasAcknowledged()) {
        response.setSuccess(true);
    }
```

The problem is that the operations on collections are `void` and if I go through the documentations -

***WriteResult.java***

```
/**
 * Returns true if the write was acknowledged.
 *
 * @return true if the write was acknowledged
 * @see com.mongodb.WriteConcern#UNACKNOWLEDGED
 * @since 3.0
 */
public boolean wasAcknowledged() {
    return acknowledged;
}
```

***WriteConcern.java***

```
/**
 * Write operations that use this write concern will return as soon as the message is written to the socket. Exceptions are raised for
 * network issues, but not server errors.
 *
 * @since 2.10.0
 * @mongodb.driver.manual core/write-concern/#unacknowledged Unacknowledged
 */
public static final WriteConcern UNACKNOWLEDGED = new WriteConcern(0);
```

I tried modifying the code to get results like :

```
collection.withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED).insertOne(document);
```

But, how do I now implement the conditional part from the previous logic with the current code?

Comment: This should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127672/mongodb-java-clients-writeconcern-doesnt-work. If not update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According  the  doc for  `MongoCollection`

```
 /**
 * Inserts the provided document. If the document is missing an identifier, the driver should generate one.
 *
 * @param document the document to insert
 * @throws com.mongodb.MongoWriteException        if the write failed due some other failure specific to the insert command
 * @throws com.mongodb.MongoWriteConcernException if the write failed due being unable to fulfil the write concern
 * @throws com.mongodb.MongoException             if the write failed due some other failure
 */
void insertOne(TDocument document);
```

Insert operation should throw `com.mongodb.MongoWriteConcernException` if the write failed due being unable to fulfil the write concern

So your code could be transformed to:

```
try {
   dbCollection
       .withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED)
       .insertOne(new BasicDBObject(someDoc));

   response.setSuccess(true);
} catch (MongoWriteConcernException x) {
   response.setSuccess(false);
}
```